# Problem connecting wireless mouse to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-mouse, canyon

I've got a Canyon wireless mouse. It worked before I switched from Windows XP to Windows 7. I don't have any drivers for it and there is no driver on the [official website of Canyon](http://www.canyon-tech.com/support/drivers) (it worked ok without them on Windows XP).
Windows 7 downloaded driver from Windows Update. Troubleshooting says that there is no problems although mouse doesn't work. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the button on the mouse and the receiver to reset the connection?

Comment: Another thing you can try is replacing the batteries (it's unlikely but possible that they became too low to work properly during your upgrade) or try another USB port for the receiver.

Comment: Apparently some Canyon wireless mice have on/off switches.  This is really a long shot, but is it possible that your mouse has a power switch and it got turned off somehow?

Comment: @boot13 You are right, there is a switch on the receiver! I am sorry for such a stupid question!
Maybe you will post this message as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Answer added.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently some Canyon wireless mice have on/off switches. This is really a long shot, but is it possible that your mouse has a power switch and it got turned off somehow?